# Response from webhook in payumoney

Tags: php, ios, payumoney

I have integrated the payumoney sdk,there is a option to save the transaction details in server by using webhook.They mentioned that we get only callbacks to the url.How do we get response without sending any request?Can anyone please help on this

Comment: A webhook is an URL you can configure on the server of payumoney. That server will then call the URL if it has something to report, and send the data relevant to that with the call. You don't have to send any requests.

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware, we have created an URL which is a post call acceptable. How can we retrieve the data from that URL, without sending a request?can you please give a clarity on this .because I don't have any idea about this type of service calls.

Comment: If it is a post call then all you need in PHP is `$_POST` to get the posted information. See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php